# Unexpected output from strtol

Tags: c, embedded, embedded-linux

I'm trying to create a small program that takes in a physical memory location and prints the data stored at the location. I'm passing two parameters into the program - the address, and the size (in bytes) of memory I want to print.

The issue I'm having is when the address I pass in gets above a certain value the strtol() function passes out a nonsensical value. Code below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <asm-generic/fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    unsigned int mem_address,mem_size;
    int loop, i;
    int *ptr, *mem_address_current;

    printf("mem_addr: %s\n",argv[1]);
    printf("mem_size: %s\n",argv[2]);

    mem_address = strtol(argv[1], NULL, 16);
    mem_size = strtol(argv[2], NULL, 16);

    printf("mem_addr: %x\n",mem_address);
    printf("mem_size: %x\n",mem_size);

    int mem_dev = open("/dev/mem", O_RDWR);

    if(mem_dev == -1)
    {
        printf("No worky\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    int alloc_mem_size, page_mask, page_size;
    void *mem_pointer, *virt_addr;

    page_size = sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE);
    alloc_mem_size = (((mem_size / page_size) + 1) * page_size);
    page_mask = (page_size - 1);

    mem_pointer = mmap(NULL,
                   alloc_mem_size,
                   PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,
                   MAP_SHARED,
                   mem_dev,
                   (mem_address & ~page_mask)
                   );


    if(mem_pointer == MAP_FAILED)
    {  
        printf("no_worky2\n");
        exit(1) ;
    }

    virt_addr = (mem_pointer + (mem_address & page_mask)); 
    ptr = mem_pointer;
    loop = (mem_size/16) + 1;
    for(i = 0;i < loop;i++) {
        printf("%#x: %08x %08x %08x %08x\n", ptr, *ptr, *(ptr + 1), *(ptr + 2), *(ptr + 3));
        ptr = ptr + 4;
    }

    return 0;


}
```

If I run the the following command, I get the expected values.

```
root@p1025:~# ./test_prog_ppc 0100000 16                                                                                              
mem_addr: 0100000
mem_size: 16
mem_addr: 100000
mem_size: 16
0x48001000: 38210020 4e800020 9421ffe0 7c0802a6
0x48001010: 2c050000 bf410008 7c7e1b78 90010024
```

However, If I change the input address the value changes from what is expected:

```
root@p1025:~# ./test_prog_ppc ffee0000 16
mem_addr: ffee0000
mem_size: 16
mem_addr: 7fffffff
mem_size: 16
```

Any ideas as to why this would happen?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: `strtol()`, as the name suggests, returns a (signed) `long`, yet you  are storing it in an `unsigned int`. It's just overflowing. What you probably want is `strtoul()`, and to store the result in an `unsigned long`. You should really be passing something other than `NULL` as the second argument also, to enable you to check for errors.

Comment: Check errno, it should be ERANGE.

Comment: Side note: better to use `printf("%p: ...\n", ptr, ...)` or `printf("%#lx: ...\n", (unsigned long) ptr, ...)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`strtol()` returns a (signed) `long`. Based on your input, you are trying to parse unsigned 32 bit numbers, so if `long` is 32 bits on your system, `strtol()` is going to go out of range. In this case, it will return `LONG_MAX`, which on your system appears to be `0x7FFFFFFF`.

You should use `strtoul()` instead, and store the result in an `unsigned long`, rather than an `unsigned int` as you are now, since while `long` is guaranteed to be at least 32 bits, `int` is not.

In addition, you really ought to be passing the address of a real pointer as the second argument to `strtol()` and friends, and using it to check for errors. Right now, if either of `argv[1]` or `argv[2]` did not start with a number, you wouldn't be able to distinguish whether the input was bad, or whether the input was a legitimate zero.

Answer (score 3):

This behaviour is documented, see [`strtol`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/functions/strtol.html)

> **RETURN VALUE**
>   ...
>   If the correct value is outside the range of representable values, {LONG_MIN}, {LONG_MAX}, {LLONG_MIN}, or {LLONG_MAX} shall be returned (according to the sign of the value), and errno set to [ERANGE].

Your return value is `LONG_MAX` and when you test `errno`, it should be `ERANGE`.

You could use one of `strtoul`, `strtoll` or `strtoull`, which all would be able to handle larger values. Although `strtoul` is restricted to `unsigned long`, so if you are on a 64 bit system, you should use one of the `strto*ll` functions.